# Should samples from np.random.normal sum to zero?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, robotics, normal-distribution

I am working on the motion model of a robot. In every time step, the robot's motion is measured, then I sample the normal distribution with the measurement as the mean and a small sigma value for covariance in order to simulate noise. This noisy motion is then added to the robot's previous state estimate.

But when I keep the robot still, these noisy measurements seem to accumulate and the robot "thinks it's moving."

Shouldn't these random samples not accumulate, but sum to zero?

In other words, would you expect the following to be true:

```
0 ~ np.sum([np.random.normal(0, 0.1) for _ in range(1000)])
```

I have tried writing out the above in an explicit loop and seeding the random number generator with a different number before taking every sample, but the sums still deviate far from zero.

Is this simply a limitation of random number generators, or am I misunderstanding the fact(?) that many samples from the normal distribution should sum to zero?

Comment: No. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables, notice the std increases

Comment: You are conflating properties of a normal distribution. Look at `np.mean([np.random.normal(0, 0.1) for _ in range(1000)])`, and that result should be what you expect right?

Comment: The *expected value* of the sum will be 0.  But the sum of a set of samples will not, in general, be 0.

Comment: No. Theoretically an infinitely large sample of normally distributed random numbers should have a mean of zero, but practically it never possible to create an infinite sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no. Be careful not to conflate the sum of an array of independent random variables and the mean of those independent random variables.

Per the article that @Hongyu Wang referenced in his comment, let's verify the following:

"If X and Y are independent random variables that are normally distributed, then their sum is also normally distributed."

Effectively, this is what you have done. You have created an array of independent random variables and taken their sum, which in turn, should be normally distributed.

I have slightly modified your code to demonstrate:

```
import random, numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [np.sum([np.random.normal(0,0.1) for _ in range(1000)]) for _ in range(1000)]

sns.distplot(x)
plt.show()
```

Which yields: [image]

You can verify that your normal distribution is correctly distributed about a mean of `0`, by doing:

```
np.mean([np.random.normal(0, 0.1) for _ in range(1000)])
```